# How to open someone's profile page with their app scope ID in native iOS Facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

From Open Graph v2.0 apps no longer can access Facebook user's actual ID, but have to deal with app scope ID. This means in iOS the url scheme link @"fb://profile/123456" no longer works, since we need user's actual ID there.

Is there a way to open user's page with only app scope ID in the native iOS facebook app?

Here is my current code, which produces a "page not found" error in native iOS Facebook app.

```
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://profile/%@", fbID];
NSURL *facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookURL];
} else {
    NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://facebook.com/%@", fbID];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hi based on this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids). So the Facebook ID it is the App-scoped User ID. So you can use same based URL schemes as well. Try to use this request to open user profile:

```
fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=%@
```

Also consider this [article](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332195860270199) about this request as well. After all it seems to me you should use Safari to show user profile.

Comment: Works like a charm! Hopefully they will document these features in the future though :)

Comment: I write code with this sample, but I always open only my profile even I insert other people's id. (I tested for many ids but always same - just opened my profile) Is there anyone who has same problem?

Comment: this solution only shows my own profile like @EdwardAnthony and @JuHong said, open with safari solved the problem: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)`

Comment: Same here, this url always opening my profile. How to open other's profile in facebook native app?

Comment: ow tnxxxxx for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
let appUrl = NSURL(string: "fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=\(id)")!

            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(appUrl) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appUrl)
            } else {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/\(id)")!)
            }
```

EDIT: This works in theory, but in practice FB don't allow FB:// URLs from third-party apps to open.

Comment: Its not working for me also its opening my profile everytime

Answer (score 1):

This URL scheme opens a user's profile page. Note that it uses the username and not the id number

```
fb://profile?id=[username]
```

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.

Comment: @ankitsuthar I'm sorry, you're saying this question was answered before but I can't seem to find the "right" answer here. I was dealing with the same problem and when I finally figured out the right way (which was not mentioned here as far as I know) I've decided to share it. Is that a problem?

Comment: ok then please make it more helpful by adding important detail regarding it. so someone can get it really helpful. @Lyn